# Passive and active pickups for bass guitar

Tags: bass-guitar, pick-ups

What is the difference in sound quality of active and passive pickups? At first it comes to me that active is best, always, but is that really true?

Also, can anyone point me if [THIS](http://www.jacksonguitars.com/products/search.php?partno=2919010503) specific bass guitar has active or passive pickups? I couldn't find this information anywhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That particular bass has passive electronics.  The difference between passive and active electronics is fairly simple.  In a passive system, the tone pot works by simply cutting frequencies.  Active electronics, by use of a power source(batteries), allow you to also boost frequencies.  This gives you greater control over the frequency spectrum coming out of the instrument(tone).  Additionally, active electronics can also boost the overall signal to compensate for the signal loss associated with cutting frequencies as in a passive system.

Which sounds better?  Totally up to the listener. You may not need the extra control of the active system, or the possible headache of losing your active EQ right before a gig when you don't have a spare 9v battery.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply @ecline6. I really appreciate that! If I'm not asking too much, can you rate that bass for me?

Comment: @HericDenis  We generally discourage product reviews on this site, since they're so subjective and not likely to help a lot of people.  I'm not a bassist either, so I'm not really familiar with the line. It looks like it gets positive reviews though, particular from metal players.